# React native Top Tap bar scrollable to specific section in a list?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, scrollspy, react-native-scrollview, react-native-scrollable-tab-view

If the user is scrolling down to Dinner option in the scroll view, then the DINNER icon should get highlighted in the tab. Similarly if the user clicks on Breakfast, it should automatically make the scroll view to move to that breakfast section. Something similar to ScrollSpytabs, how can I achieve this functionality in react native?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use `SectionList` component and custom tab menu

Try `react-native-tabs-section-list` npm library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tabs-section-list or investigate code into github repo https://github.com/bogoslavskiy/react-native-tabs-section-list